# Understanding the geometric fibre twisted differential operators

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, differential-operators

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Complex semisimple Lie algebra with decomposition $\mathfrak{n}^- \oplus \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$. For $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$, we let $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}$ be the sheaf of $\lambda$-twisted differential operators on the flag variety $G/B$ and $\chi_{\lambda}$ the corresponding central character. Further, we define the $U^{\lambda}=U(\mathfrak{g})/\ker_{\chi_\lambda}U(\mathfrak{g})$ to be the central reduction.

Assume that $\lambda$ is $\rho$-dominant; let $i:eB \to X$ denote the standard inclusion, we define the right module:
           $$\mathcal{M}_{\lambda}=i_* \mathcal{O}_{eB} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{D}_\lambda.$$

This is a right $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}$-module and a I am trying to compute its global sections $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{M}_{\lambda})$; by construction this should a right $U^{\lambda}$-module.

On the other hand, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{M}_{\lambda}) \cong \Gamma(eB,i^* \mathcal{D}_{\lambda})$ which is the geometric fiber of $\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}$ at $eB$ which is the right Verma module $M(\lambda)^r:=\mathbb{C}_{\lambda} \otimes_{U(\mathfrak{b})} U(\mathfrak{g})$.

What I do not understand is how $U^{\lambda}$ is supposed to act on $M(\lambda)^{r}$ as the obvious action fails.

Any hints or references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I must admit that I could not understand your question. $U(\mathfrak{g})$ acts on the Verma module. What does it mean "the obvious action fails"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. What I mean is that if $U(\mathfrak{g})$ acts from the right on $M(\lambda)^r$, $\ker_{\chi_{\lambda}}$ does not annihilate the module, so I do not obtain a $U^{\lambda}$-action.

Comment: Why not? With the correct normalization, $M(\lambda)$ will indeed be annihilated by a suitable central ideal. For that you need to recall Harish-Chandra's isomorphism and look how the center acts on the height weight vector.

Comment: Yes, I understand that $\ker_{\chi_{\lambda}}$ annihilates the left Verma module $M(\lambda)=U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes_{U(\mathfrak{b})} \mathbb{C}_{\lambda}$, but I am looking at $\mathbb{C}_{\lambda} \otimes_{U(\mathfrak{b})} U(\mathfrak{g})$; I understand that this too will be annihilated by a suitable central ideal, I do not see why this is $\ker_{\chi_{\lambda}}$

Comment: I can't say on the spot precisely as I am always confused initially with $\rho$-shift, $\lambda \mapsto -\lambda$ and $\lambda \mapsto w_0 \lambda$, but it is easy to find by hand the central character via which the right action will be - you use Harish-Chandra map $Z(\mathfrak{g}) \to \mathfrak{n} U(\mathfrak{g}) \cap U(\mathfrak{g}) \mathfrak{n}^- + U(\mathfrak{h})$ and apply this to the weight weight vector and see what you get (but it is always more correct to put $\rho$-shift, and one needs to be careful with it, since $\rho$ for $\mathfrak{n}$ is $-\rho$ for $\mathfrak{n}^-$, and so on)

Comment: and also it is always a bit confusing until you get used to it, that you also have similarly Harish-Chandra map $Z(\mathfrak{g}) \to \mathfrak{n}^- U(\mathfrak{g}) \cap U(\mathfrak{g}) \mathfrak{n} + U(\mathfrak{h})$, but $\rho$-shift takes care of the discrepancy

Comment: A different way of thinking would be to use the equivalence between left $\mathfrak{g}$-modules and right $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, induced by $X \mapsto -X$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ itself. Then your right Verma will become a suitable left Verma, and it is easy to compute all the swaps that take place in this situation.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the hints.